# Undefined method `convert' for Searchjoy::Search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, search

I'm working on improving the search in a Rails 4.2 project and have run into an issue with the searchkick and searchjoy gems.

In Searchjoy ruby gem (v. 0.3.2) documentation it states that we can convert a user search simply by calling `search.convert` or `search.convert(product)` for example.  But in my rails app where I use that call, I'm getting the error

```
"message":"undefined method `convert' for #\u003cSearchjoy::Search:0x0000ffff808cb010\u003e"
```

When I put in a log statement `search.methods` to find what methods are actually available, it shows that indeed, there is no `convert` method in the Searchjoy search object, but there are a lot of methods that are not documented in Searchjoy::Search such as convertable_id=, convertable_id_before_type_cast, convertable_id_came_from_user?, or convertable_id?.  These methods don't correspond with what is present in searchjoy docs.

The documentation I'm reading is the searchjoy 0.3.2 documentation as linked from ruby gems page: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/searchjoy/0.3.2/Searchjoy/Search#convert-instance_method

We are using it in conjunction with searchkick and elasticsearch.  When it's time to search, the searchjoy search id is fetched from the searchkick search results `results.search.id` where `results` is the searchkick results object, and `results.search` is searchkick's associated searchjoy search.  This is how we have the model set up for users (sought by other users):

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :searches, class_name: "Searchjoy::Search", as: :convertable
  has_many :conversions, class_name: "Searchjoy::Conversion", as: :convertable

  searchkick conversions: [:conversions]

...
  def search_data
    {
      ...
      conversions: searches.group(:query).uniq.count(:user_id)
     }
  end
...
```

Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong here?

---

Update: I updated to a version which does support searchjoy conversions.  I am also following the documentation for searchkick 3.0.  It says to use the Searchjoy::Search convert method:

```rb
   search = Searchjoy::Search.find(params[id])
   search.convert # or search.convert(item)
```

but the searchjoy search still gives me the `undefined method` error.  The class is definitely Searchjoy::Search.  I'm tempted to overwrite the class in my initializer with the convert method I see in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I missed some pertinent detail in my description.
When I was searching I was getting an error that said `WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes` for Searchjoy search fields :user_id, :search_type, :query etc. and new rows would be written to searchjoy_searches table with an id but no user_id etc filled in.

To solve this I created an initializer, `config/initializers/searchjoy.rb` with the following:

```rb
module Searchjoy
  class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :user_id, :search_type, :query, :normalized_query, :results_count, :convertable_id, :convertable_type, :converted_at
  end
end
```

instead of using the `.class_eval` method:

```rb
module Searchjoy
  Search.class_eval do
    attr_accessible :user_id, :search_type, :query, :normalized_query, :results_count, :convertable_id, :convertable_type, :converted_at
  end
end
```

The former allowed me to write to the table without errors, but it also apparently partially overwrote the Searchjoy::Search class :-(

Now I can see the `convert` method in my search instance, and I'm able to write properly to the database.

---

An alternative to doing the initializer is to fork the version of the gem and add `attr_accesible` directly in the gem.